# Line breaks don't show up right in YAML?

Tags: yaml, minecraft

I am looking at a YAML config file for a database, and all I see is a big jumble of text. However, I notice that there is a missing character every now and then if I use my keyboard's arrow keys to navigate around, I notice that there is occasionally a spot where the cursor gets stuck and requires me to press the arrow key two times instead of one. I am currently assuming that this is a line break that only YAML parsers can read. When I force a line break by pressing `ENTER`, the YAML parser does not understand the config file anymore. How can I get past this limitation without using a non-windows program? This line break has a Hex value of 0A.

---

As requested, a snippet of what the current YAML text looks like and what I would like it to look like can be found at the links below (due to StackExchange's limited use of indents. Note that these are two different files for a game's configuration. The API for the parser is [here](http://dl.bukkit.org).

---

[What I would like the config to look like](http://pastebin.com/HhuzXMUS)
[What the config currently looks like](http://pastebin.com/Jxgba2Pj)

It has also come to my attention that the second link might show it as a YAML file since it registers the line-break as a line break. However, the chunk below might give you an idea of what it looks like to me.

> RWtorchLight: Version 1.2 made by MYCRAFTisbest
>   indent1: ''
>   NOTE: 'The Meta data valuse is the number after the :'
>   For Example: Black wool, put 35 in Light_Block and 15 in Meta Data
>   Light_Block: 89
>   Meta_Deta_LB: 0
>   IMPORTANT: The torch and boots are not compatable with Meta Data yet
>   Torch_Item: 50
>   Helmet_Item: 314
>   Boot_Item: 317
>   indent2: ''
>   Torch_Use: true
>   Helmet_Use: true
>   Boot_Use: true
>   T-or-T Mode: Will create dim light when wearing pumpkin and all below features
>   Trick-or-Treat Mode: true
>   C of C: Chance of Cookie is the chance of how often trick-or-treaters get candy
>   Set to: '"0" for no chance'
>   Chance of Cookie: 5000
>   N of C: 'Will randomly chose a number between 1 and # when Cookies are received'
>   Number of Cookies: 5

Comment: First thing: what are those characters? Use a Hexeditor for this. No sense in doing anything else before you can answer that.

Comment: @arkascha The Hexeditor shows it as 0A, whereas a normal space is 20.

Comment: 0x0A (10) is a normal linebreak and yes, indeed 0x20 (32) is a space character. It might be that you face a problem with different linebreak encoding the application you use the 'view' the YAML text is not able to cope with: MS-Windows uses a different linebreak encoding as other systems (always making things slightly incompatible is _very_ important to MS...). MS-Windows uses `0x0A 0x0D` as a linebreak, whilst other systems (unix like systems) use a straight `0x0A`. See here for the YAML definition: http://yaml.org/spec/1.1/#id871136

Comment: 1) what YAML parser are you using? 2) what text editor are you using to view the YAML? 3) Does the text editor have an option to switch between "Windows" and "Unix" line endings? 4) are you sure the YAML syntax is well-formed YAML ? 5) Can you post a snippet of the YAML here on SO ?

Comment: @dreftymac 1. I am using the one given by [Bukkit](http://bukkit.org) (yes, this is for a game, but it is related to programming). 2. The text-editor, as stated in the question, is Notepad (as provided by Windows). 3. No, as this is normal Notepad. If I was able to install applications, I would install Notepad++, as that would make this question obsolete. 4. I am pretty sure that the YAML is formatted properly, as checked by an online YAML app. 5. I have updated the post with a snippet of the current and the one that I expect it to be like (note that they are two different files).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**BACKGROUND**

After reviewing your question and the associated discussion in comments, a likely case is your YAML file is being corrupted either by:

- notepad.exe;
- your FTP/SFTP/Web page/whatever used for uploading the text; OR
- a combination of both of the above

**PROBLEM**

YAML syntax is whitespace and indentation sensitive, and using MSFT notepad.exe is not recommended because it may not support the encoding specified in your YAML file.

Since YAML uses whitespace to delimit the data, any kind of modification to the text that is not consistent with the original encoding and whitespace of the original YAML will potentially render the file unusable.

This is one of the aspects of YAML that makes it potentially more brittle than alternative formats, such as JSON or XML.

**SOLUTION**

Use another editor such as Notepad++ (as recommended in the comments) or, if you do not have sufficient privileges to install another text editor, use an online text editor such as editpad (http://www.editpad.org/) to edit and save the YAML to a local file on your machine.

After saving the file to your local machine using a text editor besides notepad.exe, upload your file using an option that does not apply any kind of text filter to the text.

For example, some websites strip out characters from user-uploaded text to prevent things data corruption and security risks.

**STEP BY STEP**

- start with a known well-formed YAML file, such as the one you specified in "What I would like the config to look like"
- paste it into Notepad++ (local machine) or editpad (web-based editor)
- modify the YAML file so it matches the settings you want
- save your modifications to the original file
- upload the file via SFTP or other means that preserves the original encoding

Comment: Thank you, I am currently using Editpad. However, the problem is not that whatever is being used for uploading the file is corrupting it. It still works, it is just that I do not like that the file 'clumping together' when I need to edit it quickly.

Comment: Ah, OK, so it sounds like not using notepad.exe was the solution?

If so congrats, and have fun!